# How can I make a specific httpclient to deserialize camel case json

Tags: json, scala, jackson, finatra

I implement an API server with Finatra and my api outputs snake case json, i.e.;

```
case class A {
  val someProperty: String
}

val a = A("value")
```

`a` will be serialized int the json and vice versa

```
{"some_property":"value"}
```

But I have to access 3rd party API with camelcase json I/O, which represent above object with

```
{"someProperty":"value"}
```

I get `object MyClientModule extends HttpClientModule` via guice injector.
How can I override/change jackson configuration to a specific httpclient?

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClientModule` implicitly use `FinatraObjectMapper`. Though you can configure `FinatraObjectMapper` to serialize/deserialize JSON with camelCase, it affects the behavior globally. One simple way is to explicitly explicitly instantiate `HttpClient` with your camelCase object mapper. The another way is to define custom http client and its provider module.